# Omp critical behaves differently when parallel section creates cv::Mat

Tags: opencv, openmp

I have edited this question to (hopefully) make the problem clearer.
The following function contains two blocks of identical code. The output produced by each block is different. Specifically, while executing the first critical section, the "done" variable is not updated properly. The critical section does appear to have the effect of keeping the output from intermixing. The second block of code appears to produce the expected output. The output produced follows the code.

Does anyone have any explanations for this behavior. I am beginning to suspect a bug on Microsoft's part. I'm developing with Visual Studio 2010 Premium SP1.

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

```
void OmpTest(int iterations)
{
  int done;
  // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
  done = 0;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int ii = 0; ii < iterations; ++ii)
  {
    // do something useful
    cv::Mat frame(32, 32, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(255));

    // now update
    #pragma omp critical
    {
      ++done;
      cout << setw(3) << 100 * done / iterations << "%  " 
            << setw(3) << done << " of " << setw(3) << iterations 
            << "   ii = " << ii << endl;
    }
  }
  cout << endl;

  // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
  done = 0;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int ii = 0; ii < iterations; ++ii)
  {
    // do something useful
    cv::Mat frame(32, 32, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(255));

    // now update
    #pragma omp critical
    {
      ++done;
      cout << setw(3) << 100 * done / iterations << "%  " 
            << setw(3) << done << " of " << setw(3) << iterations 
            << "   ii = " << ii << endl;
    }
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

The output:

```
% OmpTest
  6%    1 of  16   ii = 0
 12%    2 of  16   ii = 1
  6%    1 of  16   ii = 8
  6%    1 of  16   ii = 6
  6%    1 of  16   ii = 12
  6%    1 of  16   ii = 2
  6%    1 of  16   ii = 4
  6%    1 of  16   ii = 14
 12%    2 of  16   ii = 15
 12%    2 of  16   ii = 9
 12%    2 of  16   ii = 7
 12%    2 of  16   ii = 13
 12%    2 of  16   ii = 3
 12%    2 of  16   ii = 5
  6%    1 of  16   ii = 10
 12%    2 of  16   ii = 11

  6%    1 of  16   ii = 10
 12%    2 of  16   ii = 2
 18%    3 of  16   ii = 3
 25%    4 of  16   ii = 14
 31%    5 of  16   ii = 15
 37%    6 of  16   ii = 12
 43%    7 of  16   ii = 8
 50%    8 of  16   ii = 4
 56%    9 of  16   ii = 11
 62%   10 of  16   ii = 6
 68%   11 of  16   ii = 0
 75%   12 of  16   ii = 13
 81%   13 of  16   ii = 9
 87%   14 of  16   ii = 5
 93%   15 of  16   ii = 7
100%   16 of  16   ii = 1
```

Comment: You can see from the output that the "done" variable is not updating properly in the first pass. It does update properly in the second. I do not understand how the instantiation and initialization of a cv::Mat should change the behavior of the critical section.

Comment: Have you tried to print the value of "ii" in the critical section?

Comment: I did. Too long to put here, but with 8 threads the first thread processes ii = {0, 1}. The second thread processes ii = {2, 3}, etc.

Comment: Without the creation of the cv::Mat, both blocks of code produce the expected output (the second output block).